# I want to get the id of value in a loop in a view and use it on a query outside the view

Tags: php, laravel

Im making an page that shows instruction cards. All the steps are in another table but It shows a instruction card multiple time when using 1 big query. I now have 2 queries. I loop through 1 query but in the mean time I want to use the id from a instruction card and get all the steps related to it and show it on the screen.

This is the code in the controller

```
$instructiekaarten = DB::table('instructiekaarten')
                             ->join('instructiekaart_set', 'instructiekaart_set.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
                             ->join('sets', 'sets.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_set.set_id')
                             ->join('instructiekaart_user', 'instructiekaart_user.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
                             ->join('users', 'users.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_user.user_id')
                             ->join('instructiekaart_niveau', 'instructiekaart_niveau.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
                             ->join('niveaus', 'niveaus.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_niveau.niveau_id')
                             ->select('sets.name AS sets_name','instructiekaarten.name AS instru_name', 'niveaus.name AS niveaus_name')
                             ->get();

$stappen = DB::table('instructiekaarten')
                              ->join('instructiekaart_stap', 'instructiekaart_stap.instructiekaart_id' ,'=', 'instructiekaarten.id')
                              ->join('stappen', 'stappen.id' ,'=', 'instructiekaart_stap.stap_id')
                              ->select('stappen.name as stap_name')
                              ->where('instructiekaarten.id', '$id')
                              ->get();
```

This is the code in the view

```
    @if(count($instructiekaarten) > 0)
        @foreach($instructiekaarten as $instructiekaart)
            <div class="card">
                <a href="/instructiekaarten">
                    <h5 class="card-header">{{$instructiekaart->instru_name}}</h5>
                </a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                        @if(count($stappen) > 0)    
                            @foreach($stappen as $stap)
                                <p class="card-text">{{$stap->stap_name}}</p>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>Geen instructiekaarten gevonden</p>
    @endif
```

How can I get the id from a instruction card and use it in the second query?

Comment: Better to get all these data in a single query... for the code refactoring you can create grouped scoped condtions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is put the missing field into your select:

```
->select('stappen.name as stap_name', 'instructiekaarten.id AS instructiekaart_id')
```

But you better delete your second query and add a `->with('stappen')` relation in your first query and set it up as defined here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many